# what is the natural way of rose to propagate by its vegetative cells?

Tags: botany, reproduction

I have read that rose reproduces sexually. But I have also heard that it can propagate by its vegetative cells (vegetative cells in its root). Is this correct? If yes, can I know how does it propagate by its roots?